# Xcode, Linking framework doesn't work when use custom build configuration

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I have workspace which contain two projects: main project called "MainProject" and second which is CocoaTouch Framework called "PrivateFramework".
PrivateFramework is linked to MainProject and it works well.

[image: Workspace configuration]

I also have Podfile file in project which looks like below. You can see I use XCGLogger pod in PrivateFramework and MainProject.

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

workspace 'MainProject'

def shared_pods
    pod 'XCGLogger'
end

target 'PrivateFramework' do
    xcodeproj 'PrivateFramework/PrivateFramework.xcodeproj'
    shared_pods
end

target 'MainProject' do
    xcodeproj 'MainProject.xcodeproj', 'Development' => :debug, 'Production' => :release

    shared_pods
    pod 'Alamofire'
    pod 'Unbox'
    pod 'Locksmith'
end
```

After installing pods everything is OK so PrivateFramework and MainProject is compiling and running well.

Problem is when I tried to add in MainProject new build configurations instead Debug and Release. I added Production and Development configuration which is duplicate of Release and Debug.
[image: Build configurations]
[image: Scheme configuration]

When I add new scheme to project called "MainProject Development" where I use Development build configuration (called Development) project stops compiling.
I have linking problem in my PrivateFramework which can't see XCGLogger and also this warning:

```
Target 'Pods-PrivateFramework' of project 'Pods' was rejected as an implicit dependency for 'Pods_PrivateFramework.framework' because its architectures 'i386' didn't contain all required architectures 'i386 x86_64'
```

- Why if I use custom build configuration my new scheme doesn't work
  and project stops compiling?
- Do you have some suggestions how to fix it?

Here you can find repository with that workspace: https://github.com/krystiansliwa/TestWorkspace

Answer (score 0):

I read "*you can't have a mix of debug and release for the same configuration*" from one of the CocoaPods members. And your Podfile is using the same configuration ('Development' or 'Production') for two targets (PrivateFramework and MainProject). So the implicit rules for PrivateFramework may be conflicting with the explicit rules of MainProject.

Try using:

```
xcodeproj 'PrivateFramework/PrivateFramework.xcodeproj', 'Development' => :debug, 'Production' => :release
```